# Hive-site.xml auto ctreate metastore issue

Tags: hive, bigdata

I have a windows machine and in it I have configured a **VMwire with ubuntu**.
I installed hadoop and HIVE in the **ubuntu**.
I have mysql database in my **windows**
Now I want my metastore to be created in my **windows mysql**. 
I am using the below hive-site.xml. I am getting hive prompt also, but the metastore is not being created in my windows mysql database?? **Any body has any idea about this.** Please help. Thanks !!!

**hive-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Thrift uri for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to      remote metastore.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>root</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>password</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: which hive version are you using ? please mention. because in current hive version(0.11.0) the property "hive.metastore.local" is not available. it is available as 'hive.metastore.uris'. please check

Comment: I am using hive-0.11.0...I tried with removing <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Thrift uri for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to      remote metastore.</description>
</property> and adding   <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://192.168.192.1:3306</value>
  <description>Thrift uri for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
</property>.I tired changing the local host to  ipv4 address for VMnet1 adapter, but no change.

Comment: from your VM machine are able to ping to the windows host ?,if so write a plain java code to call the mysql db, this is to check your accessibility to windows machine mysql db.